# VC++ std::system() API to return back immediately after calling CMD.exe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, system, std, createprocess

I know system() intrenally calls "CreateProcess()".

But I see 1 main difference from it's usage in application point of view.
Let's take the below sample code snippet.

VC++ Code snippet::

```
Main()
{
//Line 1 code....
//Line2 code.....
............

CreateProcess(); // Used to launch some app which needs to be kept running till the entire //program finishes.   

LaunchWindowsMediaPlayer();
...

}

}

Main()
    {
    //Line 1 code....
    //Line2 code.....
    ............

    std::system();   // // Same as above -- Used to launch some app which needs to be kept running //till the entire program finishes.

    LaunchWindowsMediaPlayer();
    ...

    }
```

**CreateProcess() USage**:

As given in 1st code snippet Say if I call "CreateProcess() in this code then immediately after launching the app uisng CreateProcess() the control comes to next line and calls  LaunchWindowsMediaPlayer();.

But in the case of system() (2nd code snippet), the control returns from system() only after it finishes execution what system(0 is supposed to do.

But say if you have a use case wherein you need to run some helper application which needs to be kept running throughout the code then it's not possible using system() API.

**Is there a way to achive this using system() API ?**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of system(), use ShellExecuteEx() API.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the underlying system (e.g. Windows, Unix, etc.).  The library function `system` passes the string to a command interpreter, which then interprets the argument according to its conventions.  In Windows, this is generally done by using the the command `start`, so rather than passing `"mycommand args"`, you would pass `"start /B mycommand args"`; the `/B` is to prevent the creation of a new window.  (Note that I've not actually tried this; my experience in this domain is in Unix, where postpending a `&` to the command is all that is needed.  But according to the documentation, it should work.)

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve to have std::system() return in windows environment ? How shall I control it from my application code where I just have the control to call std::system() with an argument ?

Comment: @codeLover What I just said: prefix the command passed to `std::system` with `"start /B"`.

Comment: `system()` spawns a new process, so function will immediately return. If you want to control this new process, you'd have to redirect it's standard input and output.

Comment: `system()` creates a new process, which is (or should be) a command interpreter; the argument of `system` is passed to this command interpreter.  Which means that anything you can do in a command interpreter can be done in `system()`.  Whether you redirect standard in and out or not depends on what you want to do (but you can, just as you can redirect them from the command line).

Comment: "after calling CMD.exe" in the title refers the question to Windows world. CreateProcess is also Windows API. The style of identifiers is also non-Unix (it is not create_process() with all lowercase).

Comment: @i486 And?  `"start /B"` is clearly a Windows solution; it won't work under Unix either.

Comment: My comment was for first sentence "It depends on the underlying system". I.e. the question does not depend to OS, because it is for Windows.

Comment: @i486 So which is it: it depends on the system (which in this case is Windows), or it doesn't.  It clearly depends on the system; my answer won't work under Unix, for example.

Comment: The question of codeLover is for use of system() API under Windows. But your answer starts with "It depends on the underlying system". So, I commented that there is no way to discuss Unix.